# How to access KubeCF?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-foundry

I am trying to use KubeCF and have deployed it and got it running on a Google Cloud K8s cluster. I have been having some problems with the system domain so, I just used the one stated in the documentation "kubecf.suse.dev", I don't feel that this is the right way as I think it is just an example for a domain, maybe, as it doesn't connect to it, but I tried using static IPs from Google cloud, but it doesn't work and the pods themselves don't run when I try using a static IP. I have also tried using 127.0.0.1.nip.io, but it also didn't work. So, how can I access kubecf or what value could I give to system_domain to make it running or using nip.io?

Comment: Perhaps jump on the #kubecf-dev cloudfoundry slack channel and one of the core team might be able to help debug

Comment: I am not in slack, I tried entering the channel, but it didn't work out. @DrNic